# Release pipeline - Which artifact goes in production?

Tags: git, release-management, gitflow, jenkins

Below is the GitFlow workflow, we are using for a project.

[image]

---

So, in our project `master` branch currently has only one *git commit* with just a *Readme* file. `develop` branch is forked from that commit. As of now, there is no other `develop` branch.

We are currently in a stage, running *Dev(build) staging of pipeline*(Jenkins) and *QA staging of pipeline*(Jenkins)

we are **yet to understand** the ***git commit*** that launch *release staging of pipeline* that generates binary artifact that needs to be deployed in production. *c1* from `release` branch or *c2* from `master` branch?

Release staging of pipeline **is supposed to** generate the release artifact that goes in production.

As per above workflow, my understanding is `develop`,`release` and `master` branch are long running branches.

`develop` branch will never be merged to `master` branch.

---

**Question:**

1) Which commit(`c2` or `c2`) launches *release staging of pipeline* to deploy the release binary artifact in production?

2) If it is `c1` commit, then do we require another pipeline for `c2`, **just to verify** the consistency of code in `master` branch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two parts to the answer here:

### 1. Fast-forward merging

Merging release into master **must** be a fast-forward merge. This means that, to merge the branches, git does not actually have to touch any files and can simply make the master branch point to the same commit as the release branch.
This can be assured by merging master into develop or release whenever there is a change in master that did not come from those two (hotfixes).

After merging release into master, both master and release must point to the same commit.

### 2. Build stability

Your build process is stable if building the same commit multiple times **must**, byte-per-byte, produce the same artifacts (maybe excluding a build timestamp if that goes into the artifact).
If your build process is not stable, *make it stable*.

---

If you address these two things, *it does not matter, which artifact you deploy*, because they should be 100% identical.

Comment: [here](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow), it says:  *Once the release is ready to ship, it will get merged it into master and develop, then the release branch will be deleted.* Can we think of deleting  `release` branch after merge with `master` and `develop`? Because hotfixes has to be applied on corresponding `release` branch....

Comment: Sure. I know Gitflow this way: you merge release into master and create a `tag` on that commit in master. The release branch gets deleted after that. If you put hotfixes through a release branch, too, its the same for those.